# RestEasy getting hostname from non jax-rs aware classes

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy, hostname

In a project I am working on I have a class that represents a Person, its a regular java object that has some jaxb annotations added. When the person is displayed as just one component in a group (a list of people for example) I only show things like firstname, lastname and a link to the persons unique page with more information. Right now when I generate a new person I pass it a link for its full page, I get the base for the link from the application context, this results with me having to manually set hundreds of urls before returning the person object.

What I would like is for a person object to have a reference to the hostname + the application path so www.example.com/application-path or localhost:8080/application-path or whatever it is in that instance. I can't hard code the url since it may change. Is there a way to either get this information in a non jax-rs aware class or can I get the information in the class that extends Application which registers my jax-rs aware applications? I basically want to only get the base url once and let each Person generate their own link after that.

My url structure is example.com/application-path/person/personID for a unique person
and example.com/application-path/person for all people. I would like each Person object to have a variable that contains example.com/application-path/ without me having to call a setter each time I create a new Person.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is in [UriInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html)

Comment: How can I get UriInfo from a class that has no interaction with the incoming url?

Comment: Injection of `UriInfo` is only supported within JAX-RS endpoints.  From your endpoint, you can pass it into other classes though.